# Finding individual filenames when loading multiple files in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I have an Apache Spark job that loads multiple files for processing using

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile(inputPath)
```

This is working fine. However for auditing purposes it would be useful to track which line came from which file when the inputPath is a wildcard. Something like an RDD[(String, String)] where the first string is the line of input text and the second is the filename.

Specifically, I'm using Google's Dataproc and the file(s) are located in Google Cloud Storage, so the paths are similar to 'gs://my_data/*.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SparkContext#wholeTextFiles](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext).

Sometimes if you use many input paths, you may find yourself wanting to use worker resources for this file listing. To do that, you can use the Scala parts of this answer on [improving performance of wholeTextFiles in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204925/pyspark-google-cloud-storage-wholetextfiles/36299520#36299520) (ignore all the python bits, the scala parts are what matter).